# How to recover missing context when transfer rtf to pdf?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have these rtf contexts which contains html tags,and I need to transfer them into a PDF file without tags,so I use itext to do the job.Here is a simple demo show what I did:

```
String context = "<p>this is a test <1mm.</p>";
try {
    //create document
    OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\test.pdf"));
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
    document.open();

    HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);
    worker.parse(new StringReader(context));

    document.close();
    file.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (DocumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The result shows follow message:

```
java.io.IOException: No message found for 1.near.line.2.column.3
    at com.itextpdf.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.throwException(Unknown Source)
    at com.itextpdf.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.go(Unknown Source)
    at com.itextpdf.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.parse(Unknown Source)
    at test.main.main(main.java:29)
```

However,if I change the context of this:

```
String context = "<p>this is a test </p><1mm.";
```

The code will run smoothly,but check the pdf,I found that the context only remains **this is a test** ,we lost **<1mm.**

I think when a single left angle bracket between a pair of tags,itext believe it is an illegal tag,so it throw an exception.When a single left angle bracket are outside of a pair of tags,itext believe it is an invalidation tag,so it erase it .

Both these circumstances may happen to my program,and after searching in stackoverflow I still can't find a solution,so I need your help.

Forgive my bad grammar.
Thank you all.

Comment: `HTMLWorker` is obsolete, I recommend to use `XMLWorker`.

Comment: And to answer your question: iText expects your HTML to be valid. To check if it is valid, you can first send it through something like *Tidy*. In this case it is obvious, you need to replace `<` with `&lt;`.

Answer (score 0):

First check your HTML with a library that checks and corrects the syntax, there are several Java implementations of *HTML Tidy*. You give it your dirty HTML, Tidy will give you clean HTML back, and you give that to iText. iText assumes that your HTML is valid and will not attempt to correct invalid HTML. (Exactly because Tidy already does that)

Comment: Thank you sir,I solve the problem by following steps:replace whole tags,like <p> with "@code1" or something,then replace < with &lt; ,then replace the tags back.A wired way,isn't it LOL